# Simulated warship quarters?

Tags: science-fiction, space-travel, space-constructs, military, virtual-reality

This universe is 500 to 700 years in the future. Navy vessels are a kilometer long cylinder with rotating hab rings. The main cylinder is basically a railgun, reactors and a bunch a nuclear missiles. The crew space is made up of the rings. The task of these ships is to guard the star gates as described in my question regarding intergalactic highways. My idea is the crew quarters can be tiny tubes for each crewman. They will lie down inside and enter into asimulation of a larger ship or even a building.  The rest of the ship is real and not a simulation. It will have to be militarized as to prevent the crew from growing complacent and dependent on the simulation. They would sleep and use their off duty time in much larger simulated quarters.This solution would make living and fighting aboard a ship much easier as well as free up room for storage and weapons. Do you see any issues with this solution and is it possible to implement?

Comment: Are you saying that the Space Navy enlistees have plenty of free time that they spend in their micro-quarters? Seems like your Petty Officers might not doing their job. There's always *something* that needs to be fixed or painted.

Comment: I just edited the question.

Comment: Is this all a Matrix-style simulation?

Comment: @Alexander As I understand it, the engineering/combat spaces are real; only the crew spaces are simulated.

Comment: @Cadence I am wondering to which level this is simulated. Can crew member fully enjoy a Jacuzzi bath while lying on a bunk bed?

Comment: Yes to both questions. But the crew simulation is of a larger more spacious ship. Having a jacuzzi would be bad for productivity and increase dependence on the sim as stated above.

Comment: Honestly seems like a bit too much of a luxury for the navy to invest in. The severs and other support systems would just take up extra room on an already crowded ship. Room that could be a workout/social area or another weapons battery.

Comment: Obviously, it's not possible (yet perhaps), but it's plausible and well established in sci fi. The essence of this has been done a billion times, so don't worry about it. Yes, I see issues, but no artificial world is ever perfect. For example, Lord of the Rings, Harry Potter and Star Wars are maybe the most well known worlds out there to the average person and downright sloppy and nonesensical. Doesn't keep people from enjoying them because they are fun. It's a fine, well known idea.Go with it. It's more important to be fun and internally plausible than to be ultra realistic

Comment: wont this screw their perception though? including to differentiating the real and the simulation one if it goes on and on, and i think it can give bad habit to soldier.

Comment: That was my question will having them be sleeping and relaxing in simulated quarters be bad for productivity.

Comment: So, the Dock Control Room from *Reloaded*. Yeah, it was too freaking bright in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your folks live in the Matrix you don't need such a big ship or gravity.**

Your giant ship with rotating rings seems like it is designed to accommodate regular crew.  In spacious quarters too - you could go for a nice run thru the gardens in a kilometer long ship.  Pretty swanky compared to a submarine or even a battleship.

Your crew pods seem like more of a storage situation where you have bodies you need to keep out of the way.  If your crew lives in tiny cylinders grooving to the fake world you can have a tiny ship and no gravity.  It is worth mentioning that if you are really doing this you need workarounds to prevent bedsores (matrix mucus?) and muscle loss (electrical stimulation?).

If you like your big rotating ship but you really want the pods for your story, maybe you have passengers and they live in the pods for the trip.  I could imagine the crew wakes one or more up because they are needed to deal with a situation.  Then maybe one of the crew is badly injured and suffering so is stowed in a pod to keep him feeling better until they can get him medical care.